# How to Solve this Problem of Duplicates in csv file? Using PHP

Tags: php, csv, duplicates

I am using PHP.
I am collecting a csv file from a server.
On the server the daily file gets rows of data appended to it.

I need to update my data-owner every ten minutes with ONLY the new data (if any).

So I need to collect the csv file, compare it with the previously collected version to see if there are any new lines in it, and then, if there are, send them to the data-owner.

I am using PHP.
How would you go about this?
Would you count the number of rows?
The first field is a timestamp - so that could be useful ?

This is what the rows look like:

```
"2023-08-01 05:54:18","Lolla","hghy557j@gmail.com", .... 20 fields more
"2023-08-01 17:44:27","Dave","dave.gt764tra@gmail.com", .... 20 fields more
"2023-08-01 17:42:23","John","john.gt764tra@gmail.com", .... 20 fields more
```

Any suggestions in PHP much appreciated !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What does "send to the data-owner" mean?

Comment: `ftell` and then `fseek` on the next run will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If the couple timestamp-user name is a uniq identifier, you can run join to extract only not paired rows.

If you have in example

```
"2023-08-01 05:54:18","Lolla"
"2023-08-01 17:44:27","Dave"
"2023-08-01 17:42:23","John"
```

and then

```
"2023-08-01 05:54:18","Lolla"
"2023-08-01 17:44:27","Dave"
"2023-08-01 17:42:23","John"
"2023-08-01 17:42:28","Pam"
"2023-08-01 19:38:15","John"
```

You can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/installing-miller/) and run

```
mlr --csv -N join --ur --np -j 1,2 -f first.csv second.csv
```

to get

```
2023-08-01 17:42:28,Pam
2023-08-01 19:38:15,John
```

- `-j` to set 1 & 2 fields as keys
- `--ur` to emit unpaired records from the right file
- `--np` to not emit paired records

Comment: OP's using PHP. Also, I think you can directly use the standard `join` command instead of `mlr`. +1 nevertheless

Comment: @Fravadona if there had been the php tag from the start, and if he had declared PHP as a requirement, I wouldn't have given a miller answer. Now you've put the php tag, and my answer has become nonsense :)

Comment: There's only an "_I am using PHP_" in the question so I don't know if PHP is a strict requirement; even if it is, PHP can call external programs so a simple solution with an other tool isn't nonsense IMHO

Answer (score 1):

As the lines are timestamped then they're probably unique, so you can save the last line of the previous iteration, search for it in the current file, and get the content after it:

```php
$file = '/some/watched/file.txt';
$tail = './saved_last_line.txt';

$last_line = @file_get_contents($tail);

copy($file, $tail) && ($fp = fopen($tail,'r+')) || exit(1);

if ( $last_line !== false ) {
    do {
        $line = fgets($fp);
        $found = ($line === $last_line);
    } while ( !$found && $line !== false );
    if ( !$found )
        rewind($fp);
}

$new_content = stream_get_contents($fp);

if ( $new_content !== "" ) {
    $pos = strrpos($new_content, "\n", -2);
    $last_line = ( false === $pos ? $new_content : substr($new_content, $pos+1) );
}

ftruncate($fp, 0);
rewind($fp);
fwrite($fp, $last_line);
fclose($fp);

# THEN DO YOUR STRUFF
echo $new_content;
```